# Two divs will not nest inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside of a parent div, but when I inspect the page, the two divs are not in a container, even though I have wrapped the div around the other 2 divs.

I want to add characteristics to the parent div, instead each div individually.

Advice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Lavu Explore</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles_sample.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <div id="sell_section">
            <h2>Sell, Manage, & Market in one easy system</h2>
            <hr class="hr_1">
            <div class="box1">
                <img id ="terminal_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/D5T6lY1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="box1">
                <p style="text-align:left">Choosing a new Point of Sale (POS) is an opportunity. Lavu   is not just accepting payments - Lavu is business management on the iPad. Upgrade your business with the Cloud POS system that was developed specifically for the restaurant / hospitality industry. Lavu has the tools you need to improve efficiency and the bottom line. Love your business.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

styles_sample.css

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 5%;
    max-width: 990px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: DIN;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: normal;
}

p {
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 150%;
} 

.hr_1 {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2% auto;
    height: 0;
    width: 400px;
    max-height: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0;
    clear: both;
    border: none;
    border-top: 1px solid #aecd37;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aecd37;
}

.box1 {
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
}

@media (min-width: 830px) {
    .box1 {
        float: left;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 830px) {
    .box1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: They're both in the parent for me. Also, how is this different from your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408344/my-divs-do-not-seem-to-be-nesting-properly?

Comment: two `box1` are inside `#sell_section`. What is the problem?

Comment: I am very new to this site, so since I wasn't getting answers, I thought I would rephrase it and make the question shorter.

Comment: Best advice is always to format your code properly. It will save you a lot of hassle like this.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't insert html start tag after your doctype, it should look a little like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 on Johnny's answer, and also markup is slightly out of whack:

You style have style rules added to `.hr_1` element, while it appears you would want to have them added to `#sell_section` - that's the id of the wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what you are after. The way I understand it you might want to do something like add a `border` or `background-color` to your `#sell_section` DIV. And at different sizes the styles are not being applied like you would like them to? If so, then the culprit is because you are **floating** your child/nested DIVs. [Floating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) can be a bit tricky to understand at first. It is definitely one of those concepts that takes a bit of practice and knowledge to understand fully.

Here's the short of what happens when you float something:

> When an element is floated it is taken out of the normal flow of the
>   document.

What does that mean? If you have this structure:

```html
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner">inner</div>
     <div class="inner">inner</div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS:

```css
.outer {
     background-color: red;
}
.inner {
     float: left;
     width: 50%;
}
```

the background color of `.outer` would not be visible because the child DIVs are floated and do not take up any space within their parent DIV. Although other elements within the parent DIV (floated or not) with them.

The solution? The most popular is know as [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). Apply that to the element that contains floated elements and it will behave as if those elements were not floated and took up space.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem! I didn't realize that floated elements do not take up space in a div. So to correct it, I added overflow:auto to my containers. This solved the problem completely. Now I can add borders and backgrounds to my divs without wondering why they aren't stretching the length of the whole container.